# позиционирование)

Tags: html, css

```css
nav a {
  text-align: right;
  color: black;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 300;
}

.top-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 110px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="top-menu">
    <li><a href="/home/">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/active/">ДИЛЕРАМ </a></li>
    <li><a href="/services/">ФОРУМ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/partners/">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Как позиционировать список по правому краю ? не получается

Comment: .top-menu li {
display: block;
  float:left;
}

Comment: не работает вообще

Comment: можете скрин скинуть как вы хотите сделать?

Comment: `padding: 300;` не верная запись нужно указать единицы измерения к примеру `padding: 300px;`

Answer (score 1):

Когда есть обертка, про нее не надо забывать

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
}

nav a {
  text-align: right;
  color: black;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 300;
}

.top-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 110px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="top-menu">
    <li><a href="/home/">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/active/">ДИЛЕРАМ </a></li>
    <li><a href="/services/">ФОРУМ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/partners/">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Измените `nav a{` на `nav {` и задайте ширину на 100%;

```css
nav {
  text-align: right;
  
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100%;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav a:hover{
  color: blue;
}


nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.top-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="top-menu">
    <li><a href="/home/">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/active/">ДИЛЕРАМ </a></li>
    <li><a href="/services/">ФОРУМ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/partners/">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```